# Converting the type of one variable to another, both types unknown. Not looking for switch or a list of if/elif/else

Tags: python, python-3.x

so something like:
*Correction:

```
def myfunc(x, y):
    if type(x) == type(y):
        print(x + y)
    else:
        x = type(y)(x) # mistake was x = type(y).__name__(x)
        print(x + y)
```

```
# Error (Not anymore, works like a charm): 
# y = typename(y)
# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

## x was int, y was string, but just assume we don't know.

Comment: `y = type(x)(y)` ?

Comment: Works!
P.S.: If casting is feasible. Say y is int and x is str.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work because `type(x).__name__` will return the name of the type **as** a string.

So assuming x's value is `'some_string'` calling `type(x)` will return

> <class 'str'>

But `type(x).__name__` will return

> 'str'

A class is callable, but a literal string is not.

You'll want to replace

```
typename = type(x).__name__
y = typename(y) # or even if only typename(y)
```

with something like.

```
my_type = type(x)
y = my_type(y) # or even if only typename(y)
```

Please note:

- y must be castable to the class of x's type. So if x is an int, and y is a string like 'abc', this method will throw a `ValueError`
- x's type must support the `__add__` method, if not, this function will throw a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

It's showing the error because you're trying to pass a value to a pure string. The value stored in 'typename' is 'str',it's just a string. Literal strings can't take in arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an `Unknown` type you can use `cast` from `typing`.  An example of this is with the Azure DevOps Python SDK

```py
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from azure.devops.v7_0.work import WorkClient

...

# The following will make work_client Unknown
# work_client = connection.clients.get_work_client()

This will ensure work_client is the proper type
work_client = cast(WorkClient, connection.clients.get_work_client())
```